# Someway to do `where booleanvalue=false` on both Sql Server and PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, compatibility, ansi-sql

I am attempting to make an application capable of running on both Sql Server and PostgreSQL.

I can not seem to find a common expression that is basically

```
 select * from table where booleancol=false
```

on SQL Server I must do(which is very confusing because the default value for bit types must be true or false, but you can't assign them to true or false or test against it)

```
select * from table where booleancol=0
```

on PostgreSQL I must do

```
select * from table where booleancol is false
```

There are quite a lot of queries in our program that does this, so I'd prefer if there was just some universal syntax I could use instead of doing `if(dbformat=="postgres")..` type crap..

Also, I'd prefer to leave the columns as boolean/bit types and not change them to integer types.. though that is an option..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SQL Server will automatically change the bit value to the varchar value of true or false.  So the following works there:

```
select * from table where booleancol = 'false'
```

I have no idea if postgre does the same thing.

Answer (score 36):

Sorry, this part is simply not true; less than half-true ;-)

> on PostgreSQL I must do
>
> `select * from table where booleancol is false`

In fact, all following syntaxes are valid in PostgreSQL:

```
select * from table where not booleancol
select * from table where booleancol = 'f'
select * from table where booleancol = 'false'
select * from table where booleancol = 'n'
select * from table where booleancol is false
select * from table where booleancol is not true
select * from table where booleancol = false
select * from table where booleancol <> true
select * from table where booleancol != true
select * from table where booleancol <> 'TRUE'
```

That's example of postgres flexible syntax, and it makes porting apps from other databases quite easy.

See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-boolean.html).

Comment: yes, but out of your list, only 2 syntaxes are also supported by Sql Server and I happened to be using what was only valid in SQL Server: `select * from table where booleancol=0`

Comment: That list isn't exhaustive, but the docs link is:  The syntax you're using (0/1 for false/true) is also valid PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

At work, we use 'T' and 'F' in char(1) columns to represent booleans in SQL Server. I'm not sure if this sort of compatibility was the reason, but it does mean that "booleancol = 'F'" would work on either flavour of database.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, take a look at an Object Relational Mapping framework, which could handle the problem of translating SQL from one RDBMS to another.

Answer (score -9):

Use an ORM, there is no need today to hand code SQL. They exist so solve the very problem you have run into.

Comment: It was downvoted because it (a) entirely fails to answer the question, and (b) pretends to know everything about OPs application.