# JPA Hibernate Postgres Error - operator does not exist: boolean = integer

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am having problem with NamedQuery when project is deployed to tomcat server on Linux machine. I have environment as:

1. CentOS 6.3
2. Postgres 8.4
3. JPA 2.1
4. Hibernate 3.2.8

NamedQuery is

```
Select dv FROM DocumentVersion dv where dv.isPublished=false
```

When this query is executed on windows machine, It works fine but when the project is deployed on server with above configuration, the pages display the exception with the following error:

> ERROR 2015-01-04 22:30:33
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ERROR: operator
>   does not exist: boolean = integer   Hint: No operator matches the
>   given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type
>   casts.   Position: 649

When I change the query to :

```
Select dv FROM DocumentVersion dv where dv.isPublished =:isPublished
```

i.e. passing boolean as parameter to NamedQuery, it works fine on both platform.

I want to know if I need to add/update any configuration on linux machine or I am doing something wrong.

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE DocumentVersion (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  uuid varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  displayName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  fileName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  fileDescription varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  filePath varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  mimeType varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  version INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fileSize BIGINT NOT NULL,
  isPublished boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Do u mean dh.isPublished  or dv.isPublished?

Comment: Its "dv". Thanks. Just Corrected.

Comment: Its a postgres issue look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948827/someway-to-do-where-booleanvalue-false-on-both-sql-server-and-postgresql .And always remember when there is problem in sql try running it in your database gui tool to find the error in sql rather than rerunning your project.

Comment: It would have been correct if I would have written a native query with JPA Hibernate. It's JPQL query. The problem seems to be with dialect rather than Postgres itself.

Comment: hibernate 3.2 will not support JPA 2.1. It is JPA 1.x IIRC

Comment: care to share the table DEFINITION here?

Comment: Sure Neil! Added in question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try with this.

```
Select dv FROM DocumentVersion dv where dv.isPublished= "false"
```

or

```
Select dv FROM DocumentVersion dv where dv.isPublished is false
```

PostgreSQL likes `"true"` and `"false"` for boolean data types.

Refer [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-boolean.html) here for more.

Comment: `"false"` and `"true"` are column names, not a boolean values. `false` and `true` are boolean values

Answer (score -2):

First guess after looking at the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html) - you should use the word `false` in UPPERCASE, i.e. `FALSE`

Comment: SQL is not case sensitive. `false` and `FALSE` are both the same.

Comment: Well the documentations says: `Using the key words TRUE and FALSE is preferred (and SQL-compliant).`